# Help with evaluating this Riemann-Sum.

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

**How to find** :$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}$${\dfrac{1}{n^3}}$$\sum_{r=1}^n {\dfrac{r^4}{(2r-1)(2r+1)}}$

**My approach:** I tried to solve this by trying to convert it into a definite integral.

I rewrote the expression as :${\dfrac{1}{4}}$$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}\sum_{r=1}^n $${\dfrac{r^3}{n^3}}$ $\Big($${\dfrac{1}{(2r+1)}}$$+$${\dfrac{1}{(2r-1)}}$$\Big)$

Now what to do after this to convert it in to a definite integral?

Comment: See my answer for a continuation of your approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{r^4}{4r^2-1}= \dfrac{1}{16}\cdot \dfrac{(16r^4-1)+1}{4r^2-1}= \dfrac{1}{16}\left(4r^2+1+\dfrac{1}{(2r-1)(2r+1)}\right)$

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^n \frac1{16} = \frac{n(n+1)}{32}$ $\sum\limits_{r=1}^n \frac{r^2}4 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{24}$ $\sum\limits_{r=1}^n \frac1{16\cdot(4r^2-1)} = \frac1{16}-\frac{n+1}{32n+16}$

From here, we simply sum these three results, and take their sum to infinity.

E.g.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^3}\cdot\bigg(\frac1{16}-\frac{n+1}{32n+16}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{24}+\frac{n(n+1)}{32}\bigg)$$

Comment: Yes I have seen your answer and I appreciate it . But you haven't really converted it into a definite integral by forming $r/n$ terms and then solved it or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes of course, but it's common practice on this exchange to lead the way, rather to solve the whole problem. I could easily do so, but at this point, its a matter of plugging in what I've given you, and doing a basic summation.

Comment: @Alphanerd Do you see now?

Comment: I do see what you have done . Thank you . Is it that there is no way to solve this summation by creating $f(r/n)$ terms and the putting $r/n$ as $x$ and $1/n$ as $dx$ ?

Comment: @Alphanerd You could, but there are a lot of not so nice limit conditions to take care of. They would make your life hellish.

Answer (score 2):

**hint:** $\dfrac{r^4}{4r^2-1}= \dfrac{1}{16}\cdot \dfrac{(16r^4-1)+1}{4r^2-1}= \dfrac{1}{16}\left(4r^2+1+\dfrac{1}{(2r-1)(2r+1)}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach can also work, but I think you forgot about a great opportunity to simplify the problem.

Instead of $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r^4}{4r^2-1}$, why don't you compute $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r^4}{4r^2}$?

If you can show that the difference is $o(n^3)$, then you win.

Comment: Are you sure about this???

Comment: Yes. Are you not??? :) Would you elaborate?

Comment: In fact, the difference is $O(n^2)$, and it is easy to prove.

Comment: I find $O(n)$ : $\frac{r^4}{4r^2-1}-\frac{r^2}{4} = \frac{r^2}{4(4r^2-1)} \sim \frac{1}{16}$, so the sum is approximately $\frac{n}{16}$...

Comment: This is better than my argument, so I am not going to show it now. +1

Comment: I really appreciate you, finding a short solution , but could you please give me some pointers on how to find the solution using my method ?. I still don't know much about Riemann Sum. All I know is , making terms like $(r/n)$ and then converting $1/n$ into $dx$ and $r/n$ term into $x$ with the appropriate limits.