# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n {\frac{r^4}{4r^2-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n {\frac{r^4}{4r^2-1}}$$
I am a class 12th student and this question is part of a previously given assignment.My solution is as follows...
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n {\frac{r^4}{4r^2-1}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}\lim_{n\to \infty}
 \sum_{r=1}^n\left({4r^2+1}+ \frac{1}{4r^2-1}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{24} \;+\;\lim_{n\to \infty}{(n/16)}+\;\;\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{16(4r^2-1)}$$
what should i do after that? , 
$\mathbf {i\,think\,answer\,is \, \infty} $

Comment: By the way, welcome to this fantastic site ! You could also notice that $\frac{r^4}{4r^2-1}>\frac{r^4}{4r^2}=\frac{r^2}{4}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i just love this community. i literally get answer withing ten minutes. Hope one day i gain enough reputation to become a moderator. It took me some time to get used to the working of this site. had to learn some LaTex commands (for the first time)....     :-)

Comment: Glad to know that you already love it ! I learn a lot here and I login every single day including weekends !

Comment: Please checkout  the JEE ADVANCED examination , FIITJEE AITS , on the internet , these are really awesome exams for 12th class students .AND SOME questions are way more advanced and require higher level maths for an easy solution.

Comment: I have asked this exact question with a slight variation . Do check that out . 
Link :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885686/help-with-evaluating-this-riemann-sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just notice that $$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{24}+\frac{n}{16}+\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{16(4r^2-1)}\ge\frac{n}{16}\ \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$ so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{24}+\frac{n}{16}+\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{16(4r^2-1)}\right]\ge\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n}{16}=+\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

You could write
$$\frac{r^4}{4 r^2-1}=\frac{1}{16}+\frac{r^2}{4}+\frac{1}{32}\left(\frac{1}{2 r-1}-\frac{1}{2 r+1}\right)$$ making, as you almost did,
$$\sum_{r=1}^n {\frac{r^4}{4r^2-1}}=\frac{n}{16}+\frac{ n (n+1) (2 n+1)}{24} +\frac{1}{32}\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2 r-1}-\frac{1}{2 r+1}\right)$$ and notice a telescoping sum
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2 r-1}-\frac{1}{2 r+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{2 n+1}$$
Adding all terms and simplifying, this would give
$$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n {\frac{r^4}{4r^2-1}}=\frac{n^4+2 n^3+2 n^2+n}{6 (2 n+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately tell the sum diverges, because as n goes to infinity, so does the terms of the sum. Think about it, what should happen as n goes to infinity ? If you are adding an infinite amount of terms, an infinite amount of them must go to cero, as n goes to infinity. Otherwise, your sum blows up!